# Calling a web service with no wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I want to write a Java program to call a web service. WSDL is not available for this web service. I have written programs to call a web service which has wsdl. Here I don't have any idea of how I can proceed. Not able to find many samples in Internet as well.

Is there any better frame work which I can use? I am getting JSON output from web service.

I am looking at options of writing a best possible case(If I could write a generalized program which could be used for many web services with out much changes, it would be great)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are several ways to consume rest service.

Using Spring framework:

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
User user = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/users/2", User.class);
System.out.println("Username:    " + user.getUsername());
```

Using apache httpclient:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/users/2");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
String userString = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
// Transform 'userString' into object using for example GSON:
Gson gson = new Gson();
User user = gson.fromJson(userString, User.class);
System.out.println("Username:    " + user.getUsername());
```

Comment: I could use Spring Rest Template. Thanks.