# Expose SOAP 1.2 web service from java which calls another REST service

Tags: java, soap, c10k

I'm a Python programmer, we have a python back-end for a web project where we use Python web server (Tornado) to offer REST web services.

Few months ago, we were asked to offer SOAP for a client, and to our surprise Python 3 has very poor SOAP exposing capabilities. We tried `Ladon` & `TornadoWS` packages but both has it's limitations. Even some of them generate invalid response which does not comply with corresponding WSDL.

So Now I think a better way is to make the SOAP interface with Java which will consume our Python back-end's web service. I've some experience in Java but that was mainly using Struts framework. I need to find a lightweight, but heavily customizable solution.

[image: Possible solution to offer JAVA soap interface which calls REST Python back-end]

What I'm currently looking for is:

- Imitate the WSDL exactly as it appears on our client's existing WSDL (Client will use our service but they want to make minimum changes).
- 100% valid soap/xml response and WSDL! (Surprisingly, some 3rd party Python packages we tried generate invalid response). The SOAP service will be consumed by .NET platforms.
- We need to have maxmimum control over generated WSDL's element names and namespaces, so that client can transparently switch to our web services.
- A lightweight solution for exposing SOAP 1.1 & 1.2 services in Java which will be scalable to many concurrent requests.
- This Java interface will call our Python back-end's REST web service. So I'm looking for something which is specifically suitable for this purpose.
- Right now we use nginx + tornado for our REST web services, I'm looking for something similar in Java. Specially, something which address [c10k](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) problem. Basically what the Java interface do will just accept SOAP requests, and make HTTP calls and return those response. So I think this is reasonable to expect something similar like [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) which offers non-blocking network I/O and scales well.

*I'm aware that this question may be  considered not constructive, but I'm really looking for some good opinion here as I did not find information in the web (maybe due to my poor searching).*

I'm also open to other possible solutions to address our problem.

Comment: simply use spring-ws

Answer (score -1):

To consume your Python REST service, check out this answer:

[Calling a web service with no wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087071/calling-a-web-service-with-no-wsdl/25088372#25088372)

To create SOAP service, you should use Apache CXF and Spring Framework (Spring MVC). Checkout this example for details: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html